# How to display multiple array result using for loop in just one dialog box

Tags: java

the problem is this: create a program that asks the user for an integer using joptionpane input dialog. then show a confirmation dialog asking the user "are you sure?. if the user clicks NO or CANCEL, a pop up message dialog will appear saying GOODBYE. if the user clicks YES, it will show a message box with numbers counting or starting from 0 to the number entered above, separated by a comma, in one dialog box.

So far this is what i created for YES:

```
if (z == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    int n[] = new int[x];
    for (int a = 0; a <= n.length; a++) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The numbers are : " + a + end);
    }
```

BUT IT ONLY DISPLAYS THE NUMBERS 0 TO (FOR EXAMPLE I ENTERED 3) 3, ONE BOX PER NUMBER. What i need to do is to display "0, 1, 2, 3" in just one dialog box

Comment: Why `javascript` tag? It must be `java`. Give proper tags to get proper answers.

Comment: @Blahh can you please mark the solution as the answer. it is usefull for later use and it's not showing as "open" anymore ;) thank you Sir.

Answer (score 1):

You open the box in the loop. That's your problem.

You have to build the string and open the box after that.

The other way: don't use a loop.

```
 if (z == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
   var s = Array.apply(null, Array(x)).map(function (_, i) {return i;});
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The numbers are : " + s.join(',') + end);
 }
```

In this example the first line is the if-statement. The second line is a javascript range polyfill (It generates an array with values from 0 to x). Last line opens the box.

**UPDATE:** The above code is javascript, not java. Here one java solution:

```
 if (z == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
   StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
   buf.append(0);
   for (int i = 1; i < x; buf.append(",").append(i++));
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The numbers are : " + buf.toString() + end);
 }
```

Comment: thanks but there's an error in "var s = Array.apply(null, Array(x)).map(function (_, i) {return i;});" it says var cannot be resolved to a type.. array cannot be resolved, _ cannot be resolved to a variable,

Comment: I'm sorry. I was looking at the tag, not so proper at your code (because it was not formatted). My Code is JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.. (y)